# Add a div after the first post in Wordpress loop

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops, posts

I am currently working on blog page for a custom Wordpress theme. This page consists of all the posts available in thumbnail format. You click a thumbnail, you go to that post. I know how to do a basic post loop so every thumbnail shows. I also know how to add HTML within that loop. However I need to know how to add a div ONLY after the first post is placed. The first post that's placed should be the latest post, thus the largest. Next to that I need another div that has nothing to do with the posts.

How do I make a loop that places a div ONLY after the first post. Then continues placing the other post thumbnails. See the image below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a basic if constuct. Before a loop starts set variable

```
$someVariable = 0;
```

then in the loop, after the post is displayed:

```
if ($someVariable == 0) {
 print "<div>whatever</div>"
 $someVariable++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew it would be something like this but I have a total black-out today..

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

2 Options:

1) Use 2 loops, one that just gets one post on top and the second that excludes that post but gets the rest.

2) Use and iterator or post_count and check:

```
if(i === 0){
    //Bigger div with unrelated dive here
}else{
    //Normal grid layout html
}
```